# Is Gradient Descent an heuristic method?

Tags: numerical-methods, problem-solving

I got in a healthy discussion with a Computer Science Professor about: Is Gradient Descent (GD) an heusristic method?

He stated is an heuristic method since can converge to different results.

I said that isn't because GD falls always to same local minima if started in same initial conditions.

I forward this discussion to MATH.SE community: Is GD an heuristic method?

What characterize an heuristic method?

Can we say that there are problems more suited to heuristics methods than non heuristic ones (first we need to define what is an heuristic).

Comment: You are trying to say that it is not an heuristic by saying that it is deterministic. Those are two different properties. Heuristic means that its output is not necessarily the actual solution of the optimization problem, in some cases it is, and some of its steps make sense in a limited information scenario.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the random version (stochastic gradient descent) avoids local traps. Is that one "heuristic" or not?

Comment: What you probably mean is a probabilistic method, bringing in a random number generator in some sensible way. A heuristic would be for example to take five steps of gradient descent, check the rate of improvement, and, if insufficient, start elsewhere, randomly selected. Or more generally, simulated annealing and genetic algorithms count as heuristic methods, as are most of the applications of neural networks. Gradient descent is completely deterministic, well connected to the underlying problem, with well-understood convergence properties. I would not call that "heuristic".

Comment: Wikip says: "A heuristic is any approach to problem solving or self-discovery that employs a practical method that is not guaranteed to be optimal, perfect, or rational, but is nevertheless sufficient for reaching an immediate, short-term goal or approximation."

Gradient descent, as an algorithm to find a "good enough" min of a function by starting at a random point and jumping in the most downward-steep direction, fits that perfectly.